# Run ASP.NET page from VS 2008 problem

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem .
When i try to run an ASP.NET page in VS 2008 using a browser(Internet Explorer,Mozilla,...), I get a "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" error. I have Windows Vista with SP1 installed.

I have tried this and I get the same error. I have even tried disabling the firewall and antivirus. I am using defauld development web server, not IIS. I have tried creating a blank project and it still does not work

Comment: Step 1: In Internet Options; Advanced, disable the "Show friendly HTTP error messages", so that you see the real error message.

Comment: Step 2 : post here if you dont get a clue about the error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't a lot to go on... are you using the default development web server? Or IIS? Have you tried a new web project (to see if it is a configuration problem)?

---

Edit;

this could have been IPv6? See "[Strange Problem - Unable to Connect to the ASP.Net WebServer on Localhost](http://www.grumpydev.com/2009/03/12/strange-problem-unable-to-connect-to-the-aspnet-webserver-on-localhost/)". Of course, based on the timing, you could be Steve, in which case hi ;-p

Comment: I have tried this and I get the same error. I have even tried disabling the firewall and antivirus. I am using defauld development web server, not IIS. I have tried creating a blank project and it still does not work

Comment: That IPv6 issue only was a problem on FF. Would cause stalls of 1 second with ajax.

Comment: It's not me :-) Definately sounds like the same problem though.

Comment: My blog post, and you get the rep.. no wonder you're on 34.4k ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried disabling Friendly Error Messages in Internet Explorer?

in IE: Options -> Advanced -> Show Friendly HTTP Error Messages. Should give you more information.

Comment: I have tried this and I get the same error. I have even tried disabling the firewall and antivirus. I am using defauld development web server, not IIS. I have tried creating a blank project and it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this post assumes you are just clicking either play or using CTRL+F5 keyboard shortcuts to run the site. Can you confirm the following after running your solution:

1. ASP.NET development webserver starts
   (you will see icon in system tray)
2. If step one is working, right click
   this select show details on the menu
3. Click the Root URL link to open a
   browser
4. Ensure your browser is open to this
   URL and can display your page
5. Ensure no proxy server settings are
   being used, or that you set no proxy
   for localhost
6. Recheck your firewall
7. Try some basic network tests by
   using PuTTY to connect to the
   ASP.NET Development Webserver (do
   google search for: Using HTTP over
   telnet)

PS: If you start VS2008 with a right click->run as Administrator, does the same problem occur?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error and browsing on Internet I found this solution.
http://accidentaltechnologist.com/asp-net/aspnet-development-server-problems-under-vista/

Basically is because the ipv6 ( You can prove it easyly, just change the word localhost by 127.0.0.1 in the URL you get when using CTRL+F5 keyboard shortcut)
Hope that be useful for you.